# Найти сайт, похожий на MS-DOS

Tags: dos

Здравствуйте, весьма странный вопрос, но всё же хочу узнать.
Однажды я наткнулся на один сайт, который был выполнен в стиле MS-DOS. Вопрос: помогите, пожалуйста, отыскать ссылку на этот сайт. Единственное что нашёл похожее, так это http://www.old-hard.ru/ но это просто оболочка, а я ищу сайт, который по дизайну очень похож на MS-DOS. Не помню уже точно, но по-моему этот сайт был как-то связан с программированием, поэтому может кто знает ссылку.. Не подумайте только ничего плохого, но очень важно найти ссылку на этот сайт.

P.S. А где храните ссылки на сайты Вы?

Answer (score 3):

http://stopwilson.com/

Сайт эмулирует MS DOS со всеми командами.

Comment: Тот сайт был очень похож на это http://habrastorage.org/storage2/b1b/bcc/793/b1bbcc7936d6b1ba9bee693b041f314d.png он русскоязычный ещё

Comment: Это W[Far Manager][1]W =) не совсем MS DOC


  [1]: http://www.farmanager.com/screenshots.php?l=ru

Comment: Короче, вот что я искал http://borland.ru/